# Clarification of pseudo-Euclidean space definition

Tags: quadratic-forms, multilinear-algebra

In the definition of pseudo-Euclidean space, we have $\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$ with a non-degenerate quadratic form $Q$ where $p,q\geq 0$, $n\geq 1$ and $p+q=n$. For $x \in \mathbb{R}^{p+q}$ we have  $Q(x_1,\dots,x_{p+q}) = (x_1^2+\dots+x_{p}^2) - (x_{p+1}^2 + \dots + x_{p+q}^2)$.

As a special case, what exactly are $\mathbb{R}^{0+1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{1+0}$? Are those the same set?

Comment: Certainly the same set but equipped with different quadratic forms

Comment: In one case the quadratic form is $-|x|^2$ (not very interesting...), in the other it is the classical squared norm $|x|^2$. Considered the same: yes and no...

Comment: @JeanMarie I think you could turn that comment into an answer so this gets off the unanswered list

Comment: @Mark S. Done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case the quadratic form is $−|x|^2$ (not very interesting...).

In the second one, it is the classical squared norm $|x|^2$.

Are they considered the same: no, because the second one is associated with dot product $xx'$ whereas there is no dot product associated with the first one.

Nevertheless, they generate the same topology.